# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request error while accessing sharepoint in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have two projects one project is .net core and another one is .net framework. I am accessing a sharepoint site using `microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll`

But I'm getting an error on `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()`.

```cs
clientContext.Load(web, website => website.ServerRelativeUrl, w => w.Title, w => w.Description);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Regex regex = new Regex(SiteUrl, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string strSiteRelavtiveURL = regex.Replace(fileUrl, string.Empty);
string strServerRelativeURL = CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl, strSiteRelavtiveURL);
//web.Context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, GetPasswordFromConsoleInput(Password));
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(strServerRelativeURL);
clientContext.Load(oFile, o => o.Title, o => o.Name, o => o.ListItemAllFields);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How can I resolve this issue in .net core?
The error I'm getting:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.
>          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
>          at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Comment: Hi, you get any answer on this? I am getting same error on .net core

Comment: Yes you can't  access sharepoint from .net framework to .net core both projects must be .net framework projects

Comment: same with me now..